# TensorFlow Android API - A way to increase log level without changing code?

Tags: java, android, logging, tensorflow, environment-variables

I compiled TensorFlow for Android and I can see that by default the VLOG level is 0.

This leads to lots of log lines such as this one:

```
tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:237 End computing. Ran in XXX ms (YYY ms avg over ZZZ runs)
```

I know that this can be theoretically solvable by setting the `TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL` environment variable.

I'm wondering if there's a way to tell my android app to set this environment variable (possibly a different level for debug/release), or must I change the JNI code and recompile in order to get rid of this log message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using an outdated version of Tensorflow.

The code that prints that log message was deleted in this commit:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/1a9769dc79fdd27c347633df210ff64f48de8d07

I would suggest updating to Tensorflow v1.1.